# jQuery Selector: How to select the children of just THIS element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

So, I have code that looks like this:

```
<span class="comic_menu mid_menu_title">    
            <ul>
            <li class="level-0 page_item page-item-264"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=264" title="Ca$h Rulez">Ca$h Rulez</a>
<ul class='children'>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-266"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=266" title="1994">1994</a></li>

    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-268"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=268" title="1995">1995</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-270"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=270" title="1996">1996</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-272"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=272" title="1997">1997</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-274"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=274" title="1998">1998</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-276"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=276" title="1999">1999</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-278"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=278" title="2000">2000</a></li>

    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-280"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=280" title="2001">2001</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="level-0 page_item page-item-101"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=101" title="Furlough">Furlough</a>
<ul class='children'>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-103"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=103" title="page 66">page 66</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-105"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=105" title="page 67">page 67</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-107"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=107" title="page 68">page 68</a></li>

    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-109"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=109" title="page 69">page 69</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-111"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=111" title="page 70">page 70</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-113"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=113" title="page 71">page 71</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-115"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=115" title="page 72">page 72</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-117"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=117" title="page 73">page 73</a></li>
    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-119"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=119" title="page 74">page 74</a></li>

    <li class="level-1 page_item page-item-121"><a href="http://www.domain.com.php5-15.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/wordpress/?page_id=121" title="page 75">page 75</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

It just goes "menu > level-0 > children > level-1". I have a bit of jQuery that looks like this:

```
$(".level-0 > a").click(function() {
           $('.level-0 > .children').toggle();
           return false;
       });
```

I'm sure anyone smarter than me sees the problem: onClick it opens EVERY 'children' element. How can I ask jQuery to open the 'children' element of JUST the 'level-0' `<li>` element I click on?

Sorry for the mess. Total n00b and the help is way appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `$(this)` and [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) in this case to find the `<ul>` relatively, like this:

```
$(".level-0 > a").click(function() {
   $(this).siblings('.children').toggle();
   return false;
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fng67/), or add some animation, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fng67/1/).

`$(this)` is the jQuery wrapped version of the current object, and since the `<ul class="children">` is a sibling of the `<a>` you clicked, [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) is what you want to find it.