# how to select the children of clicked element by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my html page, there is a list of all the categories. Each category has some subcategories. I want that as a list item is clicked, its subcategories are toggled i.e. if they are visible, they should be hidden and vice versa. Also at one time, only one list item should be able to show its subcategories. I have tried  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880374), but it doesn't help. I won't mind in using either JS, JQuery etc or changing the syntax altogether. 
My work till now is

```
<ul>
    <li class="outer-list-element">
        <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 1</a>
        <ul class="inner-list" id="inner-list">
            <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub category 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class ="outer-list-element">
        <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 3</a>
        <ul class="inner-list" id="inner-list">
            <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub category 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

css

```
li {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
   }
 .inner-list {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: none;
 }
```

Script

```
$('.outer-list-element').click(function () {
    $(this).children().toggle();
})



$(".outer-list").click(function() {
$(this).siblings('.inner-list').toggle();
return false;
});
```

Feel free to update this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7vmtd2px/1/

Comment: Pass selector to the `children()` method i.e `$(this).children(".inner-list").toggle();`

Comment: `$(".outer-list").click(function() {
  $('.inner-list').hide()
  $(this).siblings('.inner-list').toggle();
});` try this

Comment: @guradio sorry, this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code.

```js
$('.outer-list').click(function () {
   //Hide other ul
   $('ul .inner-list').not($(this).parent('li').find('ul')).hide();
   //Toggle clicked ul
   $(this).parent('li').find('ul').toggle();
});
```

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.inner-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li class="outer-list-element">
            <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 1</a>
            <ul class="inner-list">
                <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub category 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="outer-list-element">
            <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 2</a>
            <ul class="inner-list">
                <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> sub category 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class ="outer-list-element">
            <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 3</a>
            <ul class="inner-list">
                <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub category 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you update the code so that it allows only one element at a time to show the sublist

Comment: Thanks, but now it doesn't disappear when clicked again. Can we do that also?

Answer (score 1):

try With this..

```
$(document).on('click', ".outer-list", function() {
        $('.inner-list').hide(); //first hide all the element having class inner-list
        //$(this).siblings('.inner-list').toggle();
        $(this).next('ul').toggle(); // here is the trick
        return false;
});
```

and [HERE is the FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/7vmtd2px/6/)

Thanks [Mohit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38759289/3164682)

Comment: works very well. As a courtesy, can you update your answer to hide the sublist when clicked again?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class(`showInnerList` in this case) with `display:block` property. So on click of element you can add this class to the DOM which you want to show.

Also I am using `addClass` & `removeClass` instead of toggle. The reason is on click of any DOM,I intend to find the element which has `showInnerClass` and remove this same class from it & then add this same class to the sibling

HTML

```
<ul class="myList">
  <li class="outer-list-element">
    <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 1</a>
    <ul class="inner-list" id="inner-list">
      <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sub category 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="outer-list-element">
    <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 2</a>
    <ul class="inner-list" id="inner-list_1">
      <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> sub category 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="outer-list-element">
    <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 3</a>
    <ul class="inner-list" id="inner-list_2">
      <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sub category 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('.outer-list-element a').click(function() {
  $('.myList').find('ul.showInnerList').removeClass('showInnerList');
  $(this).next('ul.inner-list').addClass('showInnerList');
})
```

Also note that you are using same `id` for `ul class="inner-list"`. `id` need to be unique

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/7vmtd2px/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the same thing as Sarath's answer, but with the additional functionality of automatically collapsing the present list if it's clicked twice.

```
<ul>
    <li class="outer-list-element">
        <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 1</a>
        <ul class="inner-list" id="inner-list">
            <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub category 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="outer-list-element">
        <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 2</a>
        <ul class="inner-list" id="inner-list">
            <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> sub category 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class ="outer-list-element">
        <a href="#" class="outer-list">category 3</a>
        <ul class="inner-list" id="inner-list">
            <li><a href="#">sub category 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub category 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.inner-list {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', ".outer-list", function() 
{
    $(this).parents().siblings().children(".inner-list").hide();
    $(this).siblings('.inner-list').toggle();
});
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Somu2016/er68qnvq/1/) in case you want to see it in action.